# What does a weapon's ROF mean and how do I use it when shooting?

Tags: weapons, ranged-attack, cyberpunk-2020

The rulebook of *Cyberpunk 2020* says:

> Attack up to your weapon's maxi rate of fire (ROF), or make a melee attack.

For example my PC has

```
Arasaka Minami 10   SMG   0   J   E   2D6+3(10mm)   40   20   VR   200m
```

ROF is 20. What does this mean? Does it mean I can:

- make up to 20 separate shots with 2D6+3 damage per shot to a single target?
- make up to 20 separate shots with 2D6+3 damage per shot to several targets?
- make 20 shots only in fullauto mode?
- something else?

I am confused about this part of the rules.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Friday Night Firefight details three operating modes for automatic firearms.

1. **Single shot**: As usual. REF+Skill+d10 vs. Range+Modifiers to hit. Roll weapon damage and location if hit.
2. **Three-round-burst**: As single shot, but +3 to hit at close and medium range. 1d6/2 bullets hit the target, roll damage separately for each. *
3. **Full auto**: +1 to hit for every 10 rounds you fire at close range. -1 for medium range or more. The number of bullets that hit is the difference between the target number and your attack total. Roll damage for each separately. *

So your Minami 10 at close range can use a 3-round burst to get a +3 to hit and land 1-3 bullets, or use full auto with a +2 to hit and land up to 20 (but probably 3–12) bullets. An average of 70 points of damage. Certainly immediately fatal.

<sub>* The rules don't mention how to handle the hit locations with multiple bullets but my brief encounter with an AK-47 and a firing range tell me that with a 3-round burst, you should roll a single location but with full auto, every bullet hits somewhere else.</sub>

---

Here is an analysis of the [damage potential of the Minami 10](http://anydice.com/program/a6a1/at_least/graph)

```
╔════════╦═════════════╦═════════╦═══════════╗
║  DPA*  ║ Single Shot ║ 3-round ║ Full auto ║
╠════════╬═════════════╬═════════╬═══════════╣
║ Close  ║ 7 | 11      ║ 17 | 28 ║ 55 | 107  ║
║ Medium ║ 3 |  8      ║ 10 | 22 ║  9 |  35  ║
║ Long   ║ 1 |  4      ║  2 |  8 ║  3 |  18  ║
╚════════╩═════════════╩═════════╩═══════════╝
```

<sub>* Damage per action. The first number is the mean damage potential, the second number is the upper deviation, i.e, higher is less likely.The lower deviation is always close to or below zero.</sub>

Comment: What about trying to hit more than one target?

Comment: Divide your ROF among targets, attack each one separately. So with your Minami, you could attack two targets with ROF:10, or four with ROF:5

Comment: You might also want to add a mention of suppressive fire where, IIRC, every target in the area covered makes a save based on the number of bullets per m of area. This is good for mooks, not so good for individual targets.